# Firebase adding Dummy Authentication Records for testing without verification

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase DB setup using email authentication and need to add 10 dummy records for our testers to test with.  Since these dummy records do not have an email backing them, there is no way for me to send a verification link.  Is there a way to add authentication records to the DB and mark them as verified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Firebase Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) in an environment you control (like a server or your local machine) to create users with whatever information you choose. So, for example, if you're using Node.js, you could create a user like this and include that the email is verified. Take a look at the link to see the fields that you can include.

```
admin.auth().createUser({
  email: "user@example.com",
  phoneNumber: "+11234567890",
  emailVerified: true
})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
  });
```

Comment: prefect!   Using Node.js to do it.  Just was looking to see if there was a web front end for admins but this will work.  Thanks!